# DNS (BIND) Problems

Tags: linux, dns

I'm trying to get BIND (named) working, but am having some issues. named loads and everything, but when I do a

```
dig -x 127.0.0.1
```

I get:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.9.4-rpz2.13269.14-P2 <<>> -x 127.0.0.1
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 62929
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa.                IN      PTR

;; ANSWER SECTION:
1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa. 86222   IN      PTR     localhost.

;; Query time: 64 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.2#53(192.168.1.2)
;; WHEN: Thu Aug 07 21:47:43 PDT 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 63
```

My host isn't listed.

Here's my /etc/named.conf

```
options {

 forward first;
 forwarders { 192.168.1.2; };

 directory "/var/lib/named";
 dump-file "/var/lib/named/data/cache_dump.db";
 statistics-file "/var/lib/named/data/named_stats.txt";

 query-source address * port 53;
 listen-on { 127.0.0.1; 192.168.1.26; };
 allow-query { 127.0.0.1; 192.168.1.0/24; };
};

zone "catch22bbs.com" in {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/named/etc/catch22bbs.com";
    allow-update { none; };
};

zone "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa" in {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/named/etc/reverse-192.168.1.0";
    allow-update { none; };
};
```

Here's my /var/lib/named/etc/catch22bbs.com

```
;
;       Zone File for "catch22bbs.com" - Internal Use ONLY
;
$TTL 1D
@                IN      SOA      catch22bbs.com.  ignatius3399.gmail.com.  (
                              10             ; Serial
                              8H             ; Refresh
                              2H             ; Retry
                              4W             ; Expire
                              1D )           ; Minimum
;
             IN      NS       catch22bbs     ; Name Server for the domain
             IN      MX  10   catch22bbs     ; Mail Exchange

catch22bbs.com.  IN      A        192.168.1.26   ; IP address for the domain 
catch22bbs       IN      A        192.168.1.26   ; IP address for 'galaxy'
www              IN      CNAME    catch22bbs     ; 'galaxy' is also known as www
ftp              IN      CNAME    catch22bbs     ; 'galaxy' is also known as ftp
;
;wkstn1          IN      A        192.168.1.201  ; MANUAL IP address entry for 'wkstn1'
;wkstn2          IN      A        192.168.1.202  ; MANUAL IP address entry for 'wkstn2'
```

Here's my /var/lib/named/etc/reverse-192.168.1.0

```
$TTL 1D
@             IN      SOA       catch22bbs.com. ignatius3399.gmail.com.  (
                            10             ; Serial
                            8H             ; Refresh
                            2H             ; Retry
                            4W             ; Expire
                            1D )           ; Minimum
              IN      NS        catch22bbs.com.
1             IN      PTR       catch22bbs.com.
;
;201          IN      PTR       wkstn1.example.com.     ; MANUAL entry for 'wkstn1' 
;202          IN      PTR       wkstn2.example.com.     ; MANUAL entry for 'wkstn2'
```

I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong. Any and all help is greatly appreciated.
Thank you,
JL

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that you're looking up the wrong address.

- Your reverse zone is for **`192.168.1.*`**.
- Your `dig` command is looking up **`127.0.0.1`**.
- And `127.0.0.1` does not belong to the `192.168.1.*` network.

The second problem is that `dig` is using the system's default DNS server (192.168.1.2), and not the BIND instance that you've started on this computer. You should either change the system's DNS servers in `/etc/resolv.conf`, or manually tell `dig` to use a different DNS server using the `@address` option.

Try `dig -x 192.168.1.1 @127.0.0.1` (loopback) or `dig -x 192.168.1.1 @192.168.1.26`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. How would I correct this problem?

Comment: When I change the DNS server to 192.168.1.26 in /etc/resolv.conf, I cannot access any outside networks.

Comment: I take that back. I can, some. But, others, like IRC, I cannot.